# Does Android XML Layout's 'include' Tag Really Work?

Tags: android, android-widget

I am unable to override attributes when using <include> in my Android layout files. When I searched for bugs, I found Declined [Issue 2863](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2863):

"include tag is broken (overriding layout params never works)"

Since Romain indicates this works in the test suites and his examples, I must be doing something wrong.

My project is organized like this:

```
res/layout
  buttons.xml

res/layout-land
  receipt.xml

res/layout-port
  receipt.xml
```

The buttons.xml contains something like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

  <Button .../>

  <Button .../>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the portrait and landscape receipt.xml files look something like:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  ...

  <!-- Overridden attributes never work. Nor do attributes like
       the red background, which is specified here. -->
  <include
      android:id="@+id/buttons_override"
      android:background="#ff0000"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      layout="@layout/buttons"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This question is referred to by the Android developer tools when you attempt to use include in a way that isn't supported.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

I just found the issue. First, you can only override layout_* attributes, so the background won't work. That is documented behavior and simply an oversight on my part.

The real problem is found in LayoutInflater.java:

```
// We try to load the layout params set in the <include /> tag. If
// they don't exist, we will rely on the layout params set in the
// included XML file.
// During a layoutparams generation, a runtime exception is thrown
// if either layout_width or layout_height is missing. We catch
// this exception and set localParams accordingly: true means we
// successfully loaded layout params from the <include /> tag,
// false means we need to rely on the included layout params.
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = null;
try {
   params = group.generateLayoutParams(attrs);
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
   params = group.generateLayoutParams(childAttrs);
} finally {
   if (params != null) {
     view.setLayoutParams(params);
   }
}
```

If the <include> tag does not include **both** layout_width and layout_height, the RuntimeException occurs and is silently handled, without any log statement even.

The solution is to always include both layout_width and layout_height when using the <include> tag, if you want to override any of the layout_* attributes.

My example should change to:

```
<include
      android:id="@+id/buttons_override"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      layout="@layout/buttons"/>
```

Comment: This is ridiculous. I've never been able to get this to work, and I even saw the documentation mention needing both height and width if trying to override dimensions, which I assumed were height and width. However, all I was trying to override is margin, which isn't really a dimension. Why the heck do I need to specify both of those or even any of those when all I want to change is the layout_marginRight? Grrr, Android, sometimes you frustrate me too much.

Comment: FYI Android Lint will give you an error (Layout parameter layout_height ignored unless layout_width is also specified on <include> tag) if you are not overriding both height and width attributes

Answer (score 10):

I submitted an [enhancement request](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38023) to allow all included attributes to be overridden:

> Suppose I have two identical layouts other than the values of a
>   `TextView` field.  Presently, I either have modify the layout at
>   runtime or duplicate the XML.
>
> For example to pass two parameters with values "hello" and "world" to layout1:
>
> `<include layout="@layout/layout1a"
>   params="textView=hello|editText=world" />`
>
> **layout1a.xml:**
>
> `<merge><TextView text="@param/textView"><EditText
>   hint="@param/editText"></merge>`
>
> An alternate implementation would break encapsulation and would allow
>   the include statement to override values like:
>
> `<include layout="@layout/layout1b"
>   overrides="@id/textView.text=hello|@id/editText.hint=world" />`
>
> **layout1b.xml:**
>
> `<merge><TextView id="@+id/textView"><EditText
>   hint="@+id/editText"></merge>`

Comment: Taking into consideration the new databinding stuff, the `<include>` is used even more often now, attr overriding is a really must have feature

Answer (score 1):

I found I sometimes miss including the android:id tag when using the GUI builder in Eclipse.  Making sure (when I notice) that I add into a TextView from the builder , the id I'm using in the ListView layout.

```
<TextView android:text="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
...
```

becomes

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
...
```

Instead of getting 'false' 'false' I get :) and includes working ok.