# Will <include> override the layout_width/layout_height value?

Tags: android

I have a layout xml file named my_layout.xml, in which the root view's layout_width and layout_height has been specified as 200px.

```
<com.jlee.demo.MyLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="200px"
     android:layout_height="200px">
```

If I used this xml to be included in another xml, and specify the layout_width and layout_height as 100px.

```
<include layout="@layout/my_layout"
     android:layout_width="100px"
     android:layout_height="100px"/>
```

What would be the real width/height of my_layout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the top voted answer in this question should help you:

[Does Android XML Layout's 'include' Tag Really Work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631614/does-android-xml-layouts-include-tag-really-work)

you can only override parameters which start with layout_. so in your case, the layout should be 100*100.

Answer (score 4):

> > Overriding android:layout_below seems to not work

If you want to override any of the layout_* attributes with  tag, both layout_width and layout_height are must to be over-ridden.

See last lines of include section at http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Include