# Android: Permanently elevate View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, statelistdrawable

I have a `RecyclerView`, that has a RippleEffect as well as a StateListAnimator (which is shown below):

**anim_lift.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_pressed="true">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="translationZ"
                android:valueTo="8dp"
                android:valueType="floatType"/>
        </set>
    </item>
    <item>
        <set>
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="translationZ"
                android:valueTo="0"
                android:valueType="floatType"/>
        </set>
    </item>
</selector>
```

The question is, how would one elevate the view that is using this xml when it is clicked, and then de-elevate it when the view is clicked again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458615/how-to-use-statelistanimator

Comment: That is a StateListAnimator. i.e, it will animate an elevation then animate it off. I would like for the elevation to be permanent after the initial animation

Comment: You can also used different color when pressing set one color and again press on that color will be change that type of logic also applied...

Comment: That isn't the desired outcome. The result needs to be for the view to be elevated once selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by using the selected state of the View. If you click the View you `setSelected(true)` and when you click it again `setSelected(false)`.

```
yourView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.setSelected(!v.isSelected()); // toggle selected state
    }
});
```

The selected state then can be handled by the StateListAnimator. You may add a new item to catch `state_selected="true"`:

```
<item android:state_selected="true">
    <set>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:valueTo="8dp"
            android:valueType="floatType"/>
    </set>
</item>
```

Now if the View is selected it will have an elevation of `8dp`. If it's not selected the StateListAnimator will fall through to the default elevation of `0dp`.

Comment: Ah it works, but not where I need to use it. If you refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673988/android-include-with-rippleeffect-statelistanimator, I need to elevate each item that is selected. I will mark correct as you've answered my question. could you assist me further? Regarding the elevation of the items in that question. Thanks