# How to Re-using Layouts with <include/> with parameters?

Tags: android

I had a problem ,that is I have some ViewGroup,which have almost the same content. like this:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView android:text="aaa"/>
    <ImageView android:src="bbb"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout>
    <TextView android:text="ccc"/>
    <ImageView android:src="ddd"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to convert to this:

```
<include layout="xxLayout"
    param1="aaa"
    param2="bbb"/>
<include layout="xxLayout"
    param1="ccc"
    param2="ddd"/>


xxLayout.xml
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView android:text="{param1}"/>
    <ImageView android:src="{param2}"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I know I can do it use java code.Could it be possible that just use xml ?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This is possible using only xml, thanks to the databinding library:

First wrap `xxLayout.xml` in a layout and add a databinding class definition that lists the variables you want to pass into the included layout.

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable name="myText" type="java.lang.String"/>
        <variable name="mySrc" type="android.graphics.drawable.Drawable"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout>
        <TextView android:text="@{myText}"/>
        <ImageView android:src="@{mySrc}"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Then use the databinding library to inflate the including layout and inject the desired values using databinding statements. See the [databinding library documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions) for details on the databinding expression language and what it supports.

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout>
        <include layout="xxLayout"
            app:myText="@{`aaa`}"
            app:mySrc="@{@drawable/bbb}"/>
        <include layout="xxLayout"
            app:myText="@{`ccc`}"
            app:mySrc="@{@drawable/ddd}"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Don't forget to include in your build.gradle file for it to work: dataBinding { enabled = true }

Comment: If you're getting error: attribute x unknown, make sure parent layout also begins with <layout>

Answer (score -2):

You can use this

```
           <include
            android:id="@+id/banner"
            layout="@layout/login_banner" />
```

banner is the id of the include Tag and login_banner is the different layout which you want to inflate in your XML

Comment: @Apurva Didn't get you ?

Comment: What I understood from question is, OP also wants to add custom (or may not be custom) attributes 'param1', 'param2' to included layout. You're not showing that in your answer.

Comment: No... It not just has different "android:id",it also have some other params like "android:src" ,"android:text".

Comment: The requested solution is to pass more values in the include tag to achieve more reusable behavior. e.g. Placeholder of an EditText to show different placeholder texts if included in multiple layouts.

Answer (score -4):

use like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
             android:id="@+id/vgroup1"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             layout="@layout/viewgrup1"" />

    <include
                android:id="@+id/vgroup2"
                layout="@layout/viewgrup2"" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No... It not just has different "android:id",it also have some other params like "android:src" ,"android:text".

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631614/does-android-xml-layouts-include-tag-really-work)

Answer (score -6):

You can use a custom viewgroup with attibute param1,param2. include is not match your demand

Comment: I knew it. that is the thing I don't want to de.I was think about that there is must be a way without java code.but it's not.

Comment: include is not support custom parms