# Android: re-using layouts using include with parameters

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I'm creating an ordered list with a custom styling which is used in multiple places. I try to avoid extra code and to create a re-usable layout file for the list item, which can be included to ordered list with certain parameters. How I could do that?

What I have now is following:

layout_ordered_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="order"
            type="java.lang.String" />

        <variable
            name="text"
            type="java.lang.String" />
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/order"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@{order}"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
            android:text="@{text}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Then I would like to use that layout like following:

layout_ordered_list.xml

```
<LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/layout_ordered_list_item"
       bind:order="1"
       bind:text="First text content"/>
    <include layout="@layout/layout_ordered_list_item"
       bind:order="2"
       bind:text="Second text content"/>
    etc.
</LinearLayout>
```

Note that I'm not interested about setting variables in code dynamically. I use these layouts only with hard-coded values (or with string resources) like in my example. But since I'm using these so many times, I don't want to copy-paste list item again and again just to alter order and text content. I also know that my example is not working, it's here just to demonstrate how I would like it to work.

I've already searched the answer from Android documents but there is no example like that.
https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#includes

Pretty much identical question has been also asked before in SO but there is no usable answer either: [How to Re-using Layouts with <include/> with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36617322/how-to-re-using-layouts-with-include-with-parameters)

Comment: I think your last link does answer the question. You'll need to create a Compound Control/Compound View: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound

Comment: @MorrisonChang This sounds a very complex approach considering what I want to achieve. I really hoped there would be some simple solution.

Comment: May be of use: https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-list-tricks-ef3d5630555e

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve what you want by using the databinding library to inflate the including layout, and then passing in the hard coded text using a databinding statement.

Details on the databinding expression language can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions).

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout>
       <include layout="@layout/layout_ordered_list_item"
           bind:order="@{`1`}"
           bind:text="@{`First text content`}"/>
        <include layout="@layout/layout_ordered_list_item"
           bind:order="@{`2`}"
           bind:text="@{`Second text content`}"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```