# Databinding on "included" Layout's variable is empty

Tags: android, layout, include

I'm trying to pass a value through to an included Layout and thought @M.Pomeroy's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36617322/how-to-re-using-layouts-with-include-with-parameters) was perfect. However when I tried implementing it the passed value doesn't come through. Here is a simplified example of what I am trying:

MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="W00t!"
            />

        <include
            layout="@layout/included_layout"
            android:id="@+id/the_included_layout"
            app:theWord="@{`Woof!`}"
            />

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="W00t!"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

(the two TextViews are just to give an indication as to where the included layout should appear on the screen)

included_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
    <data>
        <variable
            name="theWord"
            type="java.lang.String"
            />
    </data>

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{theWord}"
            android:textSize="48sp"
            android:background="#22FF0000"
            />
</layout>
```

(The red coloured background is just to show where the included TextView is)

And this is what I have in my app's build.gradle file:

```
android {

    . . .

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
    }

    . . .

}
```

And finally, this is what the output looks like:

[image]

As you can see there is no text in that red coloured TextView.
I have also tried wrapping that "included" TextView in a LinearLayout and things but that didn't help.

Any idea what I have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, got it sorted.

Turns out instead of inflating with `setContentView(...)` I had to use `DataBindingUtil.setContentView(...)`.

However simply adding `DataBindingUtil` causes an "Not enough information to infer type" error so the final line I used was:

```
DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main) as ViewDataBinding
```