# Toolbar partially showing in landscape view

Tags: android

I have a landscape view of an activity in my app where the toolbar at the top is partially showing. The toolbar's width spans end to end in the portrait view, but when I rotate the emulator, the toolbar is condensed and just showing in the middle at the top of the landscape view(see image below). The design view in Android Studio shows the toolbar in the landscape file going across the top like normal.

[Landscape View w/partially shown toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjaUC.png)

I've designed a separate landscape view of this activity. I use an include statement in both the portrait and landscape views. The toolbar used is a separate xml file.

Here is the landscape xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativePaperboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".PaperboardActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        layout="@layout/toolbar2"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="104dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:text="@string/textPaperboard"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/topRectangle"
            android:layout_width="112dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_rectangle_stroke"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_image1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="152dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="104dp"
                android:layout_height="104dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/paperstencilscutout162"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="104dp"
                android:layout_height="104dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/paperbasesection162"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="104dp"
                android:layout_height="104dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/finpapbasesection162"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="104dp"
                android:layout_height="104dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/paperlrsectiontrace162"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="104dp"
                android:layout_height="104dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/finpaplrsection162"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_textview1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="136dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="216dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="104dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:text="@string/cutOutStencils"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="104dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:text="@string/traceBase"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="104dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:text="@string/traceCutGlueLR"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="104dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:text="@string/cutLiving"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="104dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:text="@string/cutLiving"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_image2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="136dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="280dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="104dp"
                android:layout_height="104dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/paperbrsectiontrace162"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="104dp"
                android:layout_height="104dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/finpapbrsection162"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                android:layout_width="104dp"
                android:layout_height="104dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/paperlrsectiontrace162"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                android:layout_width="104dp"
                android:layout_height="104dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/paperlrsectiontrace162"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_textview2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginStart="136dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="392dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="104dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:text="@string/glueLiving"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="104dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:text="@string/glueLiving"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="104dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:text="@string/traceBed"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="104dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:text="@string/cutBed"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the toolbar xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I didn't think I needed to include any Java code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: add   `android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to the `include` tag check for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631614/does-android-xml-layouts-include-tag-really-work

Comment: Thanks. I did what you said and the toolbar is still the same. I also  read the link you provided. The funny thing is on two of my activities, the landscape view works fine as far as the toolbar goes. Maybe I should take out the include tag all together, or return to the default action bar.